# Disable paging from Data View web part

Tags: 2010, xslt, data-view-web-part

I am new to XSLT and possibly the question i am asking could be a candy for some of you.

I have added a Data View Web Part on Page using Sharepoint Designer 2010. I am using this DVWP to display data from pages Library. It uses Paging and Displays 10 records per view.
I am filtering this data based on certain IF conditions but not getting the required output. The reason is that the data needed to satisfy the condition is on later views.

I tried to work on XSLT to disable paging and ended up destroying my web part. I tried to find out some info regarding this but no luck.

Could some one please help disable paging to display all data in one view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this section in the declaration of the webpart :

```
<RowLimit Paged="FALSE">0</RowLimit>
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to manipulate the web part settings manually in the code. These settings are also available on the ribbon. Select the DVWP in SharePoint Designer 2010 in Design View and then use the Paging command on the Options ribbon of the Data View Tools:

[image]